# How to deploy linked Maven Projects

Tags: maven

I have **ProjectAPI.war**, **ProjectPorcessing.jar** and **ProjectRaw.jar**. All are maven projects.

**ProjectPorcessing.jar** use **ProjectRaw.jar** as custom dependencies. 
**ProjectAPI.war** use **ProjectPorcessing.jar** as custom dependencies.

If i install -

**ProjectRaw.jar** as 3rd party jar to **ProjectPorcessing.jar** 
and **ProjectPorcessing.jar** as 3rd party to jar to **ProjectAPI.war**

1) do i need to deploy **ProjectRaw.jar** along with **ProjectPorcessing.jar** and **ProjectAPI.war** to web server (**widlfy**)?

2) OR just deploying **ProjectAPI.war** to web sever is enough?

If i link all 3 projects(by declaring inside **pom.xml**) , how shall i deploy to web server?

1) Deploy **ProjectAPI.war** along with **ProjectRaw.jar** and **ProjectPorcessing.jar** ?

2) Or just deploying **ProjectAPI.war** is enough?

Besides, if i need to replace the **installed JAR (installed as 3rd party jar)** to a project, which kind of technique will be the best practice? 
Do i need to *remove existing jar first*? IF **yes**, which is the best practice to *remove the existing JRA file*? For now, I simply **reinstall** by using *mvn install:install-file* and i am not sure my technique is right though.

Appreciate your help guys, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you build a war, the jars that you list as dependencies will be packed into that war. So it is enough to deploy the war to your Application Server (Wildfly).

If you need new versions of the jars (or other jars), change the dependency entries in your pom.xml, build again (`clean install`) and then deploy the result on Wildfly.

Comment: Thank you :) Appreciate it.